# Is it possible to get a resolution that is better than what is given by the Rayleigh criterion?

Tags: optics, visible-light, camera, imaging, image-processing

I remember reading recently that it is possible to unblur a face that has been blurred by using a computer to process multiple images of the blurred face from different angles. This got me thinking, is it possible to get an image resolution better than what is given by the Rayleigh criterion for other objects? Even for angles smaller than the angular resolution, wouldn't one still get some information about the object? Would it be possible to get an angular resolution that is better than what is given by the Rayleigh criterion by, for instance, taking multiple images of an object at slightly different angles and then using a computer to reconstruct finer details?

Answer (score 0):

The Rayleigh criterion is a suggestion for the minimum separation of two images, so that they can be resolved (two can be seen instead of one).

It's often possible to have the images more separated and easily resolved.

If you mean is it possible to resolve images that are separated by less than the Rayleigh criterion using different points of view, with each view giving a separation less than the Rayleigh criterion - that's an interesting question.

Yes it is likely to help resolve the images, but there is likely to be a limit on how much information can be gained.  Images at different wavelengths could help.  Anything that would 'sharpen' the images would help, so that the maximum of one image fell on the minimum of the other.